# Give the Cumulative Density Function: how did we arrive to this result?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function

I'm having some trouble with the following application:

Let $f$ be the function defined on R by:

$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
a.3^{-x}&\textrm{if }x>0\\
a.3^x&\textrm{if }x<0.
\end{array}\right.
$

**1)** Determine $a$ so that $f$ is a PDF.

**2)**  Let X be a random variable that admits $f$ as a density. Give the CDF of X. Show that X admits an expectation $E(X)$ and calculate it.

I know that for $f$ to be a PDF one of the conditions is it has to integrate to 1, so I did that and computed $a$ to be equal to $a=\frac{\ln 3}{2}$ for $f$ to be a PDF. What I have a problem with is the second question.

For $x<0$ **:**
I computed $\displaystyle\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{x}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{-\infty}} \dfrac{\ln\left(3\right)}{2}{\cdot}3^x\,\cssId{int-var-mathjax}{\mathrm{d}x}$ = $\dfrac{3^x}{2}$
Which is consistent with the correction given with this practice question. Where they lose me is for $x>0$ **:**

$\displaystyle\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{x}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{0}} \dfrac{\ln\left(3\right)}{2}{\cdot}3^{-x}\,\cssId{int-var-mathjax}{\mathrm{d}x}$ = 
$\dfrac{-3^x+1}{2}$

Which is not the same as the correction given with the exercise, they computed that integral as such:

$F(x)=F(0)+\int_0^xe^{-t\ln 3}dt=1-\frac{3^{-x}}{2}$

Which is slightly similar to my answer but obviously not the same. When I ran the integral through an online integral calculator it gave the same answer that I arrived to, so that was even more confusing. And I didn't want to just assume that there was some typo in the correction and move on with a potential gap in my knowledge.

Also, I do understand the properties they used to convert the original equation to a logarithmic exponental form, but I don't understand why they introduced the variable $t$ (since that's something we usually do to deal with improper integrals) and what was the use of that $F(0)$ in the beginning?

I hope someone more knowledgeable can help me deal with this confusion. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why that part wouldn't show, but it's equal to integral from 0 to x of ln(3)/2 * 3^(-x)

Comment: How can you have an integral in which one of the bounds of integration ($x$) is also the variable being integrated over?

Comment: I just started with calculus 5 days ago from scratch, so I'm still weak on the subtle nuances. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Use some other variable for integration, say $z$ (or $t$ as in your last integral), if you want to integrate from $0$ to $x$, otherwise it can lead to confusion (as well as being technically incorrect.)

Comment: Thanks ! Will do so from now on. What do you think of the other question?

Comment: Draw the graph of the PDF.  Under it sketch the area represented by the integral when $x\gt 0.$  Break that area into two parts at $x=0.$  Evaluate the parts separately, then sum them.

Comment: It's fine. I just re-did the calculations and I see what I was missing. Thanks.